# Why Object.isPrototypeOf not available in normal objects

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

I am able to access `Object.getPrototypeOf` method, but why is the same not available for instantiated objects?

```
const obj = {}
obj.getPrototypeOf // is not a function
```

Comment: It’s a static method on Object, it makes no logical sense as an instance method

Comment: Because [getPrototypeOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) is a static method of `Object`.

Comment: Because that's not how the language runtime was designed. The method is associated with the constructor Object, not with the prototype object for all object instances.

Answer (score 1):

It's a static method, you can't use it on an instance.

Try instead:

```js
const myObj = Object.create({})

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(myObj))
```

Answer (score 1):

The main reason, as others have noted, is that it's a static method on the `Object` constructor, not an instance or prototype function. So the correct way to use it is `const proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(theObject);`. But read on for why you might not have wanted to use an object method for this even if it did have one.

Objects do have a `__proto__` accessor property **but using it is a Bad Idea™** because A) The object may not have it,¹ and B) Even if the object does have it, it may *lie* to you, just as it can with the prototype method `hasOwnProperty` that checks to see if the object has an "own" property with a given name. That opportunity for the object to lie is one motivation for moving away from putting these things on the prototype (along with avoiding web compatibility problems and improving JavaScript engine performance). Recently, a new static method on `Object`, [`Object.hasOwn`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwn), was added to replace the prototype function `hasOwnProperty` specifically because of this issue. Like `getPrototypeOf`, it's a static method on `Object`, not a prototype method, and it won't lie to you. *(Proxy objects notwithstanding.)*

So in those rare situations you need to get the prototype of an object, just do it via `Object.getPrototypeOf(theObject)`.

---

Example of objects with no `__proto__` accessor property:

```js
// A basic example of an object with no __proto__ accessor property:
const o1 = Object.create(null);
console.log("__proto__" in o1);              // false
console.log(o1.__proto__);                   // undefined
console.log(Object.hasOwn(o1, "__proto__")); // false
console.log(o1.__proto__);                   // undefined

// Here's another one, and this one has a prototype
const o2 = Object.create(
    Object.assign(
        Object.create(null),
        {
            method() { console.log("Hi there"); }
        }
    )
);
console.log("__proto__" in o2);              // false
console.log(o2.__proto__);                   // undefined
console.log(Object.hasOwn(o2, "__proto__")); // false
console.log(Object.hasOwn(o2, "method"));    // false
console.log("method" in o2);                 // true
o2.method();                                 // "Hi there"
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it's a static method (it's meant to be used on a class, not an instance)

Example:

```js
class X {
  static getX() {}
}

const x = new X()
// works
X.getX()
// throws
x.getX()
```